# Detect bluetooth FW hang in bluez stack

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to implement an application using bluez.

The issue is :
If sometimes the Bluetooth controller Firmware goes into bad state, my application hangs.
There is no way to recover, except through a power reset.

The solution I can think of is implementing a timer after sending the hci command to the controller.
Is there any preferred way to do it in **bluez user space**?
Or does this have to be handled at the application layer only?

Comment: Do you mean `HCI` commands?  The supported APIs from BlueZ are the managerment API or the D-Bus API which are both documented at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc. Using `HCI` commands could conflict with the `bluetoothd` that BlueZ runs. This is maybe why you are seeing issues.

Comment: Hi, yes @ukBaz using mgmt commands also same query I have. What if the controller stops responding, how to recover from such a situation. The solution I have shared above works, but I need to know how to use it in bluez stack not in application.